# Access form - update one field filter from code without conflicting existing filters

Tags: ms-access, filter, vba

I have a subform, and it has a field with code source (custom VBA function doing a lookup). The filter button on that field doesn't work (Access by design). My users will want to use filters for this field and also for other fields.

As a workaround, I have added 3 checkboxes. If a user clicks any one of these checkboxes, filters get applied to the subform based on the function field.

The problem is, this removes all the other currently applied filters from the subform. This is not nice towards my users.

*Is there a way to add and remove one field criteria to filtering without ruining the rest of the filter?*

I have tried brute forcing it, but I gave up. When a filter gets added the normal way, many parentheses and `AND` words get added. My little filter text can be anywhere in a maze of filter criteria string. So using text functions to find it and manipulate it seems to be big, slow, stupid, unstable and dirty.

Am I missing something here? Any better way to do this?

```
Dim tx As String

If Not Me.flProcDONE And Not Me.flProcNOK And Not Me.flProcOK Then
  tx = ""
Else
  tx = "stProc IN (" & IIf(Me.flProcDONE, kStProcUPD, "99") _
       & "," & IIf(Me.flProcNOK, kStProcNOK, "99") _
       & "," & IIf(Me.flProcOK, kStProcOK, "99") & ")"
End If
With Me.sfrApply.Form
 .Filter = tx
 .FilterOn = True
End With
```

---

(Partly-working) brute force code:

```
  With Me.sfrApply.Form
 
    If .Filter = "" Then
      .Filter = tx
    Else
      If tx = "" Then
        lnStart = InStr(1, .Filter, "AND stProc IN (", vbTextCompare)
        If lnStart > 0 Then
          lnEnd = InStr(lnStart, .Filter, ")", vbTextCompare)
          .Filter = Left(.Filter, lnStart - 1) & Mid(.Filter, lnEnd + 1)
        End If
      Else
        lnStart = InStr(1, .Filter, "stProc", vbTextCompare)
        If lnStart > 0 Then
          lnEnd = InStr(lnStart, .Filter, ")", vbTextCompare)
          .Filter = Left(.Filter, lnStart - 1) & tx & Mid(.Filter, lnEnd + 1)
        Else
          .Filter = "(" & .Filter & ") AND (" & tx & ")"
        End If
      End If
    End If
    .FilterOn = True
 End With
```

It has a few errors, misses some parentheses. Making it work would require an additional 4-5 `IF`s and many more `Instr`s. Disgusting. Access filtering keeps adding `[]` and `()` to the filter text, that is what makes it near impossible to manipulate from the code.

A few examples of `.Form.Filter` texts:

> "" - no filter
>
> "stProc IN (99,99,1)" - the one I'm trying to manipulate
>
> "([scrCarrierInvoiceGLSQuote].[ctParcelQUOTE] In (1,2))"
>
> "((([stProc] In (99,99,1)))) AND ([scrCarrierInvoiceGLSQuote].[ctParcelSI]=1)"
>
> "(([scrCarrierInvoiceGLSQuote].[ctParcelQUOTE] In (1,2))) AND (stProc IN (99,99,1))"
>
> "((([scrCarrierInvoiceGLSQuote].[ctParcelQUOTE] In (1,2)) AND ([stProc] In (99,99,1)))) AND ([scrCarrierInvoiceGLSQuote].[lsError] Like "COD?")"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I did manage to solve it. There was no nice way I have found. Basically:

- If the filter string is empty, just add my filter string to it
- If the filter part in question is not already in the filter string, just Concatenate it to the end of it (as @iDevlop suggested)
- If the filter I'm about to apply is already part of the filter, just change the "IN(...)" part of it - never attempt to remove it.

Here is the code:

```
Dim txFullFilter As String
Dim txFilterPart As String

Dim lnStProcPos As Long   'Position of the column name in the existing filter text
Dim lnOpenParPos As Long  'Position of the opening parentheses "(" after column name
Dim lnCloseParPos As Long 'Position of the closing parentheses ")" after the opening one

'Create the actual filter text form the column I'm trying to filter from outside.
  If Not Me.flProcDONE And Not Me.flProcNOK And Not Me.flProcOK Then
    txFilterPart = "0,1,3,7"
  Else
    txFilterPart = IIf(Me.flProcDONE, kStProcUPD, "99") _
         & "," & IIf(Me.flProcNOK, kStProcNOK, "99") _
         & "," & IIf(Me.flProcOK, kStProcOK, "99")
  End If
  txFullFilter = "stProc IN (" & txFilterPart & ")"

'Apply said filter to the subform
  With Me.sfrApply.Form
    If .Filter = "" Then
      .Filter = txFullFilter
    ElseIf InStr(.Filter, "stProc") > 0 Then
      lnStProcPos = InStr(.Filter, "stProc")
      lnOpenParPos = InStr(lnStProcPos, .Filter, "(")
      lnCloseParPos = InStr(lnOpenParPos, .Filter, ")")
      .Filter = Left(.Filter, lnOpenParPos) & txFilterPart & Mid(.Filter, lnCloseParPos)
    Else
      .Filter = .Filter & "AND " & txFullFilter
    End If
    .FilterOn = True
  End With
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like

```
With Me.sfrApply.Form
 .Filter = .Filter & " AND " & tx
 .FilterOn = True
End With
```

This is just a quick sample but you can elaborate on that.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the effort, but I've got this far. Now, assume the user turns on one more filter manually, so your filter text will have something like `blah blah AND (stProc IN()) AND blah blah`. Now go and turn off or change my filter, without ruining all the other filters in effect. **This** is what I'm asking about, this is the tricky bit.

Comment: Indeed. How do the users do to filter the subform ? You could perhaps use the `OnFilter` or the `OnApplyFilter` event to save the user's filter base to a string variable ?

Comment: Well, I have tried that. The problem is, Access automatically appends the filter string. So I can save the whole filter string, not just the newly added part, and that doesn't really help. Should I add some filter strings to the question to make it more clear?

Comment: If I understand you well, the real issue is to distinguish the filter part set using the Access standard interface from the filter part set using you checkboxes, right ?